# PyODBC Access only Runs basic Select Queries

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, ms-access, pyodbc

I have recently been trying to migrate Access Files to an Oracle database, and to do so, I use PyODBC to access the data within the Access Files. I am using python 3.6 64 bit and have the proper ODBC 64-bit drivers for Access.

I was able to quickly access the information using:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ='+path)
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('select Field1 from Status')
for each in cursor.fetchall():
    print(each)
```

This gives me the information I need:

```
(213, )
(21213, )
(3232, )
(123123, )
(23232, )
(3123, )
(231233, )
(53535, )
(3232, )
(13, )
(31331, )
(31231231, )
```

But it seems that I am unable to use any Access functions on any of the columns, for example:

```
cursor.execute('select CStr(Field6) from Status')
```

Does not only not return anything, but exits the program without an Exception being able to be caught or any other trouble shooting possible, It simply exits. I have tried this exact query in Access itself and it works perfectly, although the Access version I open it with is 32-bit (I don't know if this would affect anything). Where clauses that also work in Access do not work at all.

Please help with any information.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error with that single `CStr` `SELECT` query. Can you show some sample data of *Field6*? What is its original data type?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, either. [This code](https://pastebin.com/G6Jy3emW) works fine.

Comment: This is why I am so confused, it seems as though it should work, but I recieve nothing. The weirder part is that normal select statements work. I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: Can you provide a download link for an .accdb or .mdb file that can be used as part of a [mcve]?